# How can get results from Laravel database query builder as array by default always?

Tags: database, laravel

Hi i'm trying to get a results from database query builder but i dont want the results as stdClass but always as array how can do that?

```
$users = DB::table('users')->get();
```

Comment: you can get array by attached argument at the end of your statement.

$users = DB::table('users')->get()->toArray();

Answer (score 0):

This will return a collection. You can use `->toArray()` method.

```
$users = DB::table('users')->get();

print_r($users->toArray());
```

If you want to make sure that everything will be an array:

```
$users->map(function($item){ return (array) $item; });
```

Answer (score 0):

For performance reasons, it is better that you explicitely convert to array query results, only when you need it, by appending `->toArray()`:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->get()->toArray();
```